# How to download image from URL Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

So I am trying to download images from url link and then trying to add them to an array of downloaded images but running into trouble.

**I have** searched stackoverflow and related sites, but could not find similar issue.

There are two kinds of images that I am downloading.

Example of 1st type is : http://img.youtube.com/vi/7lC3UZtLa6Y/0.jpg

Example of 2nd type is : http://master.dextra.xyz/_uploads/photos/image_111.webp

Please click on both to see the difference

I have no trouble downloading the first type, simply by using the following code. But as you can see the second url link would download itself on clicking and hence I get nil when extracting it

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

 // Downloading image 1
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://img.youtube.com/vi/7lC3UZtLa6Y/0.jpg")!)
            self.downloadedImages.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)
// No problem downloading above image, also shows up in my app

      // Downloading image 2
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://master.dextra.xyz/_uploads/photos/image_111.webp")!)
            self.downloadedImages.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)
        // getting nil in UIImage(data: data!), although it says that data is around 300000 bytes.

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // Updating UI
       });
    }
```

So, how can I download images of second type? It downloads it successfully. But cannot access it  because it stores in computer somewhere, I am not sure about it though

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried your code. The image is successfully downloaded in the second case. The reason why you are getting `nil` instead of valid UIImage is unsupported image format. Here is the list of supported formats:

Tagged Image File Format (TIFF)

Joint Photographic Experts Group (JPEG)

Graphic Interchange Format (GIF)

Portable Network Graphic (PNG)

Windows Bitmap Format (DIB)

Windows Icon Format (.ico)

Windows Cursor (.cur)

XWindow bitmap (.xbm)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/LoadingImages/LoadingImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH17-SW7

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for prompt response! Is there a work around? Other than converting images to JPEG or something else in the backend?

Comment: Thanks guys :) I found following project on github: https://github.com/seanooi/iOS-WebP I have not tried this but what developer stated in the description sounds promising.

Comment: Thanks @IgorB. I have accepted your answer. The library that you offerred has an option to convert from webp. I think it would be better if I do that in the backend to improve front end experience. One last question is that do you have any clue why ios doesnt support webp? Is there a quality issue or something?

Comment: @AkshanshThakur I guess that performance matter. Not pretty sure about this, but as you know WebP offers better compression results - probably it's algorithms also consume more

Comment: @AkshanshThakur regarding quality loosing - this format provides both options - you can compress you image in loose or lossless representation